# Math problem for $6$th grade

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The total rainfall in Seattle last July was $1.86$ inches. What was the average daily rainfall in that city in July?

Answer (score 4):

Recall that July has $31$ days. If the total rainfall over a month i.e. $31$ days is $1.86$ inches can you compute the average daily rainfall?

$$\text{$31$ days $\to$ $1.86$ inches}\\ \text{$1$ day $\to$ ? inches}$$